# Conditionals in dict comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to simplify modifying massive dictionaries that change numbers around a lot (from datestrings to python dates, Decimal to floats, etc), and I want to be able to determine if something even needs changing (maybe I only want to change some numbers, not dates):

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qualification_callback=None):
    if qualification_callback:
        dictionary.update({k: callback(v) for k, v in dictionary.items() if qualification_callback(v) else k: v})
    else:
        dictionary.update({k: callback(v) for k, v in dictionary.items()})
    return dictionary

d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}

def bigger_than_two(number):
    return number > 2

def double_it(number):
    return number * 2

transform_dictionary(d, double_it, bigger_than_two)

# expecting {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 6, 'four': 8, 'five': 10}

transform_dictionary(d, double_it)

# expecting {'one': 2, 'two': 4, 'three': 6, 'four': 8, 'five': 10}
```

I'm reading about dict comprehensions but don't see a way to do what I want, either do my computation or leave the value unchanged. Is there a way to get the results I want from the above?

Comment: Any reason this needs to be a dictionary comprehension?

Comment: You're making the fairly common mistake of mixing up the `if whatever` in a comprehension's filter clause and the `if whatever` in a conditional expression `x if whatever else y`. What you're trying to write is a conditional expression, but because the comprehension-specific filter syntax looks like the same thing, you're trying to put the `if whatever` where the filter would go.

Comment: I just thought the comprehension would be easiest. I wanna be able to transform dict values that fit a criteria for huge dicts

Comment: do you only have double_it and bigger_than_two, or you might have more?

Comment: I would know exactly what I wanna do and why in this case, like convert all Decimal class to 4 digit floats, convert all "2015-03-15" strings to Dates, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comprehension like this could do what you want

```
def transform_dictionary(dictionary, callback, qualification_callback=None):
        return {k: callback(v) if (qualification_callback and qualification_callback(v)) or not qualification_callback else v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: so from the `k:` to the `for` loop refers to what to do about the value, `v`?

Comment: Correct, thats the logic to choose which value to use

Comment: I don't know whether to thank you or python, that's clean. Thanks

Comment: can you also pick between multiple possible keys in these comprehensions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: This does not give the OPs expected output when the `qualification_callback` argument is left out. Your dictionary comprehension should be `{k: callback(v) if qualification_callback and qualification_callback(v) or not qualification_callback else v for k, v in dictionary.items()}`.

Comment: @pzp You're right, I updated the comprehension. It's becoming a bit unwieldy though and at this point I would probably want to split it up.

Comment: @rtemperv Another option is to make `lambda _:1` the default value for `qualification_callback`. Although I would say that the "unwiedly-ness" of the `or not qualification_callback` fix is the lesser of two evils in comparison to the "hacky-ness" of this fix.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary comprehensions with conditions take the following structure:

```
new_dict = {key:VALUE_1 if CONDITION_1
            else VALUE_2 if CONDITION_2
            else VALUE_3 for key in myDict.keys()}
```

here is a simple example, hopefully you can see how it works and modify it to 
suit your particular application.

```
myDict = {"a": 4, "b": 7, "c": 55, "d": 432}
new_dict = {key:"greater than 100" if (myDict[key] > 100)
            else "10 to 100" if myDict[key] > 10
            else "10 or less" for key in myDict.keys()}
```